# Get stream of raw samples from audio signal using AudioToolbox - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, signal-processing, audiotoolbox

I would like to record an audio signal with my iPhone and then I would like to access the samples of this signal one-by-one. I found some similar examples online but I never found an example (in Swift) to actually read and manipulate all the raw samples. How can I do that using Swift?

Comment: This is quite broad and very hard to understand. It would be great if you would be more specific in what you want to do and show us some CODE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, I was finally able to create an array of floats where to store and manipulate the audio samples, doing the following:

```
   let file: AVAudioFile!
    do {
        file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: mySourceURL!)
    } catch {
        print("Error:", error)
        return
    }
    let totSamples = file.length
    let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
    let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(totSamples))
    try! file.read(into: buffer)
    var floatArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buffer.frameLength)))
```

where mySourceURL! is the URL of the recorded signal.